# On the growth of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, asymptotics

I have read this fact: for any two functions $f$ and $g$, we have that $\sqrt{fg}$ has a growth that is between $f$ and $g$.

Now I am asking you: for reciprocal functions? I mean, take $f = \dfrac{1}{x}$ and $g = \sqrt[3]{x}$.

For any negative $x$ to $0$ the growth of $f$ is $-\infty$, while $g$ is some real number.

The growth of $\sqrt{fg}$ is infinity.

Is that fact wrong, or am I wrong and why?

Thank you!

Comment: When you read "this fact", do you remember any caveats? Because you've encountered the big one.

Comment: @Arthur Actually no, when I read that "fact" there was no objection or caveat written... Can you explain more please?

Comment: @Hans-André-Marie-Stamm Does that "fact" hold for $f(x)=x, \,g(x)=1\,$, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are both strictly negative, then $fg$ and $\sqrt{fg}$ are strictly positive, and so clearly cannot lie between $f$ and $g$.

If only one of them is negative, then the square root doesn't exist, so that's even worse.

As long as $f$ and $g$ are both non-negative, $\sqrt{fg}$ must always lie between $f$ and $g$. That fact you read should *always* be accompanied by this restriction.